# Can UITableView Section Headers be Changed when They are 'Floating'?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

On iOS devices the section headers in UITableView's have a nice behavior where they stick or 'float' to the top of the screen as you scroll through a section. The section headers in my particular case are loaded from other XIB files.

Is it possible to change the section headers depending on whether or not they are currently floating? Specifically I'd like to add a small shadow to appear under the header only while it's stuck to the top of the view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it yet, but I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be possible.
Just make sure you set the right `bounds` (because your shadow needs to be on top of your view, not above it).

You can use the following approach:

1. Use `scrollView:didScroll:` to get notified about scroll-events.
2. In this method, check whether you need to add your shadow-view to your (floating) header-view.
3. If so, add it. (just `[view addSubview:shadowView]`.) Something like `CGRectMake(0.f, yourDefaultHeaderHeight, 320.f, yourShadowHeight)` should be the `frame` of your `shadowView`.
4. Now, update the `bounds` of `view`, so it can show your `shadowView`: `CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f - yourShadowHeight, 320.f, yourDefaultHeaderHeight + 2 * yourShadowHeight)`.
5. When you find out that your header isn't floating anymore (by using `scrollView:didScroll:`), remove the shadow-view.

Your `headerView`s `bounds` should be `0.f - yourShadowHeight` because if you use just `0.f`, it'll blur (I don't know why ...).

Comment: Thanks Tim. Could you expand a little on step 2? How can you determine if any given header view is floating or not?

Comment: `BOOL isFloating = (headerView.frame.origin.y + scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0);` =)! (I'm not sure whether `contentOffset.y` is a positive number or a negative one, so if it doesn't work, replace the `+` with a `-` :)!

Comment: For some reason the header origin and content offset don't quite line up when the header is floating, and adding a little wiggle room made the shadow flicker in and out.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I got something similar working. I'll post it below when I can.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the function I created to update whether each header has a shadow or not. All the section headers in this case are a UIView subclass `ListHeader`. They're retained and returned by the `viewForHeaderInSection` function.

```
- (void) updateHeaderShadows {
    int i=0;
    int sectionHeight = 0;
    int totalHeight = 0;
    UIView * sectionHeader;
    while (i<[self numberOfSectionsInTableView:self.tableView]) {
        sectionHeight = [self.tableView rectForSection:i].size.height;
        sectionHeader = [self tableView:self.tableView viewForHeaderInSection:i];
        if ([sectionHeader respondsToSelector:@selector(shadow)]) {
             if (sectionHeader.frame.origin.y == totalHeight || sectionHeader.frame.origin.y == totalHeight + sectionHeight - sectionHeader.frame.size.height) {
                 [((ListHeader *) sectionHeader).shadow setHidden:YES];
             } else {
                 [((ListHeader *) sectionHeader).shadow setHidden:NO];
             }
        }
        totalHeight += sectionHeight;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to have your own UIView in the header. Then you would need a reference to it. Then hook into `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` with your UIScrollViewDelegate. In that function, add the shadow to the custom view.

Hook into `scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:` and remove the shadow in this function.

Answer (score 0):

@Anthony Mattox answer for Swift

```
protocol SectionHeaderWithShadowProtocol where Self: UIView {
    var shadow: Bool { get set }
}

class SectionHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView, SectionHeaderWithShadowProtocol {
    @IBOutlet weak var shadowView: UIView!
    var shadow: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            shadowView.isHidden = shadow
        }
    }
}


func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    updateHeaderShadows()
}

func updateHeaderShadows() {
    var i = 0
    var sectionHeight: CGFloat = 0
    var totalHeight: CGFloat = 0
    while i < numberOfSections() {
        sectionHeight = tableView.rect(forSection: i).size.height
        if let sectionHeader = tableView.headerView(forSection: i) as? SectionHeaderWithShadowProtocol {
            if sectionHeader.frame.origin.y == totalHeight || sectionHeader.frame.origin.y == totalHeight + sectionHeight - sectionHeader.frame.size.height {
                sectionHeader.shadow = false
            } else {
                sectionHeader.shadow = true
            }
        }
        totalHeight += sectionHeight
        i += 1
    }
}
```